# A conversation about stew

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

"Add to the stew."

"Victor will go ballistic.  There's too much."

"No, the amount's fine.  It spoils slowly, have no fear."

"Um… really?"

"Maybe?  I seem to recall we had some stew for months."

"Baloney.  Unless maybe if it was frozen. Otherwise, there's no way."

"Everyone ate from it, remember?  Even that senator, what's her name again?  Higgins or something?"

"Rep. Heckles, and, um, she got sick from it."

"Shoot, you're right.  Okay, never mind.  Let's leave the stew as is."

---

A hint, added later:

> Paragraph breaks are important, but sentence breaks (aside from the paragraph breaks) are not.

Another hint, added even later:

> [literature](/questions/tagged/literature)

Another hint, added even later:

> Paragraph word counts are important, but sentence word counts are not.

Another hint, added even later:

> [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) — specifically, looking something up in an online database

Another hint, added even later:

> The number of paragraphs is a multiple of three.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, first of all we notice

> that the first letters of the lines spell out AV NUMBERS. "AV" could mean a lot of things, but with the [literature] tag in a hint it's probably the so-called Authorized Version of the Bible, which of course has a book called Numbers.

We will need

> chapters, verses, and presumably word numbers or something. Another hint tells us to look at word counts; that gets us the numbers 4 7 10 2 11 11 15 9 12. That's an odd number of numbers, so definitely not just chapter/verse pairs, but it could be chapter/verse/word triples. Looking up Numbers 4:7 word 10, etc., we get "A FORTY THREE".

Now

> one thing to wonder about is the OEIS, which gives its sequences numbers prefixed with "A". It pads them all to 6 digits, though, so it's A000043 rather than A43 ... but a later hint indicating looking things up in an online database seems to suggest that maybe this is what we want. A000043 is the exponents for the Mersenne primes.

And now

> (after trying several other possibilities) indexing into *all the words*, 1-based, by the Mersenne exponents 2, 3, 5, 7, ..., 61 gives TO THE VICTOR GO THE SPOILS HAVE SOME REP. Thank you, don't mind if I do.

Comment: The [_Britannica_](https://www.britannica.com/topic/King-James-Version) spells it as you do, while [the British Library](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/king-james-bible) spells it with an _s_, as I'd expect. I don't know who's right (or why the _z_ might be).

Comment: You're referring to the word "authorized"? Either is fine. For the most part, British English speakers prefer -ise and US English speakers prefer -ize. I go against that trend, as does the Oxford University Press (and, I am guessing, the Encyclopaedia Britannica), on etymological grounds: -ize comes from Greek -izein. I _don't_ follow US English in the spelling of e.g. "analyse" which is from ana + lusein. There are also some specific words (e.g., "realise" in the sense of "notice") where I'm just too used to the -ise spelling and the "make it so" sense is absent, and I stick with -ise :-).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, going to take a first stab.
Perhaps the answer (or part of it) is:

> To the victor go the spoils

First we notice:

> The acrostic:  AV NUMBERS

This might refer to:

> Aperture Value on cameras, represented by f-stops

Looking at common values for that,

> we can find words in the text that start on those values on each line.  If you count the letters on each line and stop on common f-stop values, these words generally fall on them.  (1,4,11,22, etc.)

> These jumped out at me and they follow the pattern except for the first "the" which lands on 6 (not a common f-stop value).

> [image]

I feel like there may be more to it, but wanted to give this a shot and see if anyone can build from there if there is more to it.

Comment: rot13(Gur npebfgvp jnf vaqrrq cynprq gurer ba checbfr, ohg lbhe vagrecergngvba bs vg vf abg jung V vagraqrq.  Frr zl erprag rqvg gb gur dhrfgvba.)